# angular ui-router $stateParam.id is null on first call

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

In ui-router, I have nested states and one of them has a stateParam.

When I navigate to this state from within my app, all goes well and `$stateParam.id` is populated but when I try direct link to `app/event/1` its null.

```
   $stateProvider
    .state('root.app', {
        url: "/app",
        templateUrl: "app/partials/app.html",
        data: {
            authenticate: true
        },
        controller: function ($scope, $state) {
            $scope.loadingView = true;
        }
    })
    .state('root.app.event', {
        url: "/event/{id:[0-9a-fA-F]{1,8}}",
        templateUrl: "app/partials/event.html",
        data: {
            authenticate: true
        },
        controller: 'EventController'
    })
```

any ideas?

Comment: How are you linking to the root.app.event state?

Comment: usually with ui-sref and this works! I try to access it directly from full url like http://example.com/app/event/1/. this would alow me to redistribute the url. but it doesnt work for some reason.

Comment: Do you have html5 enabled? If not, you may need to add the hash: example.com/#/app/event/1

Comment: i dont, but my url in my previous comment is wrong I use http://example.com/#/app/event/1 . which works but `$stateParams.id` is null and `$state.url` is `"^"`

Comment: Interesting, to be honest I am not sure at the moment. Just for arguments sake, could you test it after changing your `.state` url to read `/event/:id`?

Comment: @Asok just did, doesnt make a difference. thanks

Comment: ok I am a complete retard! I was not reinjecting params in when re-routing from `$stateChangeStart`. I changed `$state.transitionTo(toState)` to `$state.transitionTo(toState, toParams)` and now its obviously fine! thanks for your time!

Comment: Haha, not a problem. Glad you got it working. Best of luck